# Is there a way to animate objects when sliding down the page/

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, adobe-xd

so, I am new to Adobe xd and I am trying to create a landing page and what I want is when I slide down the page, the content float up or animate in general. Is this possible? If it is not possible how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating a same artboard that will be the tsansactioned stage of the animation you need, and you can use as type of transition: scroll-to.